# Is it safe to mass delete users from the database directly

Tags: users, database

We have a client site that has been getting a lot of spam registrations. We're turning on [`purgePendingUsersDuration`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#purgePendingUsersDuration) to help deal  with some of these automatically, but I was planning to go into the database to delete a bunch in bulk directly (since there are almost 200 of them)

Is it safe to delete them just from `craft_users` and `craft_usergroups_users` tables? Are there other places I should watch out for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to delete users (or any other elements in Craft) directly from the database, the place to do that is the `elements` table. Delete the row(s) from there, and all the elements’ rows in the other tables will go away automatically.

Comment: I want to delete a lot of "pending" users. I can't see where in craft_elements what is what. There isn't a column to differentiate them from "active" users?

Comment: Not to worry, purgePendingUsersDuration seems to work great!

Comment: Is this still the case for 2020? Table `elements` or `elements_sites`. `craft_elements` does not exist.

Comment: @JessicaTalzor still valid, yes. You should definitely have an `elements` table (possibly prefixed with something depending on your `tablePrefix` setting).

Comment: For anybody wondering, this still works in 2024!